# Setting the webserver to an EBS directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, amazon-ami

On my previous question
[Saving changes to an EC2 instance without having to register an AMI each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245436/saving-changes-to-an-ec2-instance-without-having-to-register-an-ami-each-time)
 I asked how was posible for me to save files to my spot instance without having to register a new `AMI` each time. I researched and it looks like attaching an `EBS` volume is a way of saving data persistently without having to register an `AMI` each time I make changes.

The new issue I have is that I need to "call" files in the `EBS` volume via cron and treat them as webpages. They are mostly `PHP` files.

I tried setting up my `EBS` under `/var/www/html` but AWS prevents me to do that suggesting me to use `/dev/sdf` instead

Is there anyway I can set my `EBS` volume under my webserver so I can call my files on the `EBS` using the cron and interpret them as valid `PHP` files?

Any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/sdf` is a block device and `/var/www/html` is a mount point.  They're completely different things; analogous to a physical book and a bookmark.

You first have to attach your EBS volume to your instance.  It will show up as `/dev/sdf`(or whatever device name you've specified).  You then have to create a file system on it using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf`.  You then mount the newly created volume using `mount /dev/sdf /var/www/html`.  To have it automatically mount at boot, edit `/etc/fstab` and append the following to the file:

```
/dev/sdf    /var/www/html     ext4      defaults,noatime    0      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie for your answer and explanation. I will be testing everything now. As I stated the instance is a persistent spot instance. If I edit /etc/fstab and register a new AMI and a new spot request for that AMI it will always create the AMI with the EBS attached, right?

Comment: When I use spot instances, it's for batch processing that takes an input, does something, and outputs persistent data into an S3 bucket.  I've never had the need to use them with additional EBS volumes.  So I'm not really sure, but probably not.  You could write a script that uses the AWS API to attach it at boot though, if not.

Comment: Yep, I will find a way. I am testing right now so I can confirm your solution. Thanks again